# Embedded WordprocessingDocument into SpreadsheetDocument with Open XML?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, spreadsheet, word-processor

How can this be done? Let me know if you all have solutions.

Embedded WordprocessingDocument into SpreadsheetDocument with Open XML

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function AddEmbeddedPackagePart() or AddEmbeddedObjectPart() in the OpenXml API to accomplish this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.maindocumentpart.addembeddedpackagepart.aspx